# Mirror modifier, but not quite. Is there a phantom modifier?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, mirror

I need help, tried to google and seems I do not google the right keywords.

I need the thing like mirror, but not quite.

I want to mirror specific mesh object few exact places and edit the source mesh and see it reflected 3 other places.

Mirror modifier makes one copy - I need two, and each of them placed somewhere in space. I need that I can change position of each of the "phantom" meshes.

Is there such modifier or approach?

Any ideas much appreciated,

Comment: To make more copies with Mirror modifier add more Mirror modifiers. Modifier depends on object origin point (if with default settings) or Mirror object (if setting it in the settings). Change these and you will control behaviour of mirroring.

Comment: Perhaps linked meshes can help. You can duplicate object to share their meshes by pressing Alt+D

Comment: @HenrikD awesome, the one thing I needed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

We'll start with this mesh (I extruded a face so it isn't symmetric):

[image: Mesh]

Go to the `object` tab and add the object to a group:

[image: Group]

Now, create an empty. Go to the `object` tab and set the duplication to the group you just created:

[image: Duplication]

Now, to mirror the object, simply make the `x-scale` of the empty negative. It will become flipped. Since Blender is smart enough, the normals will be alright.

[image: Flipped]

Now, you have a flipped copy of the object that will change if you change the original. You can repeat this if you need more copies, and you can position them as you wish:

[image: Result]

Comment: Note that normals will look alright while actually not being. This can come up upon exporting or working with baking. It's best to apply scale which will freeze object transforms and inverted normals problem will become apparent

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate your object using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to avoid creating a new mesh. Instead the same mesh data will be used and if you edit one you will also edit the other. You can also link mesh data between objects by selecting two objects and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. Then select Object Data in the menu that appears. Or you could go to the mesh tab of the properties and right at the top select which mesh should be used by this object.